# "po" command in Xcode 4.6 is very slow the first time

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.6

I upgraded to Xcode 4.6 and whenever I debug and I execute "po" for the first time to inspect an object, the debugger takes like 1 minute to return. After that, every "po" command will work fast as usual.

Are you guys seeing this as well? Any fix?

Thank you

Comment: Nope, that is not what I get. Works just as good as it did before in prior versions.

Comment: This is the effect of the phenomenon called "dynamic linkage". Also, Xcode is Xcode and not xCode.

Comment: Changed to Xcode, thanks. So if it is because of "dynamic linkage", how come @Till is not experiencing it? Does it have to do with some settings? Thanks

Comment: Because I do use a machine with 8GB of RAM and an SSD, I guess.

Comment: @LocoMike I'd say it may or may not be actually visible (depending on the exact OS version, more precisely the implementation of the loader/dyld, the phase of the Moon, etc.)

Comment: I'm running Snow Leopard on an Air so that might make sense. I think it is time to ask for an upgrade then :) Thanks guys, I wish you had replied so that I could mark it as answered.

Comment: @LocoMike, is that issue when doing a po an array element. I noticed that when po array[32] element for example but not regular pos. This by the way happens on an iMac with 8MB Ram. If you answer yes, then it is a bug.

Comment: @Spectravideo328 it happens almost every time, even with simple views. But as I said before, it only happens the first time. I run a 4GB Air, so that might be the reason.

Comment: You're not alone mike, SSD, 8 gigs of ram, 2.6 i7. PAINFULLY slow. (as in I was able to open chrome, google it and post this comment just in time for the object to print)

Comment: @endy What OS are you using? I'm on Snow Leopard. Sorry to hear it is slow for you as well... well, not very sorry as it is good to see other people seeing it, but I share the pain :)

Comment: Mountain lion. Latest version.

Comment: Ok, then I'm clueless... Have you seen people talking about this beside this thread?

Comment: I don't have a fix, but I can say that it has nothing to do with 8 Gb of RAM and an SSD. I have both, and I'm experiencing the same problem. Mountain Lion, mid 2009 MBP. Sometimes takes a minute to display. 

It's also not likely to be permissions. I recently rebuilt my primary drive from scratch, and migrated all my settings. The problem remains.

Comment: I see the same problem, it was introduced with 4.6. I suggest we all write a bug on Xcode, so that Apple can fix it.

Comment: At the risk of being voted down, this is a prevalent bug which makes debugging worse than in 4.5.2 (a difficult feat).  I propose (given @fishinear 's suggestion) that Apple be petitioned for a fix.

Comment: i see this painful 4.6 delay when trying to print in integer value: > p n

Comment: Still slow in 4.6.1. :-(

Comment: @fishinear do you know what the best way to report a bug to Apple is?

Comment: @TomJowett Use bugreporter, http://bugreport.apple.com, and login with your developer account. You cannot see bugs that other people have reported, but you can report your own bugs. See https://developer.apple.com/support/resources/bug-reporting.html for more info.

Comment: much obliged, thanks @fishinear (edit: I just reported bug #13430971 if there's any way for people to get on board, though from what fishinear described it may not be possible to see/add to other bug reports)

Comment: You cannot join an existing bug. You'll need to report your own bug (I reported one earlier as well). Apple puts priority on bugs based on how many people have reported it.

Comment: I've only noticed this when I am debugging on a device, in the simulator it is not noticeable.

Comment: as a coda I just went out today and bought a new rMBP with 8GB and I can guarantee this is not a system issue (it still hangs like maddd when running a po)

Comment: I started a bounty to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988445/how-do-i-quickly-inspect-the-value-of-an-arbitrary-variable-in-xcode-4-6-x/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upgrading to 4.6.2 fixed this problem for me in Xcode

Comment: I read they improved LLDB performance for debugging. Well, this is closed! Thanks for sharing the pain everybody ;)