# Xcode 4.6 Strange issues with Debugger."po" command does not work

Tags: xcode, debugging, lldb, xcode4.6

I just recently upgraded to xcode 4.6 and strange things are happening to the debugger. "po" command ceases to work some times. Also step by step debugging sometimes does not work. Is anybody else having the same issues

Comment: I am having the same issues. PO and P just takes longer (5 seconds+ sometime).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760206/po-command-in-xcode-4-6-is-very-slow-the-first-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the issue with this. I checked the Optimization Level for your Apple LLVM Compiler code compilation in target settings, changed it to None and now the debugging works as it should

Comment: PS: if you have compiler optimization turned on, step by step debugging works but based on the optimized code of the compiler which is likely not in the same sequence as your code. And that is why it is off by default on debugging and on for release. On the other hand, I am curious to see if you still encounter the po problem. I have that po problem even with no compiler optimization.

Comment: Upgrading to 4.6.2 seems to have fixed the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760206/po-command-in-xcode-4-6-is-very-slow-the-first-time

Answer (score 0):

Just try to clean up everything from Project menu, delete derived data folder from organizer. Exit and restart XCode. It may clean up some garbage memory and set things up. I have experienced that it improves po a bit.