# How do I quickly inspect the value of an arbitrary variable in Xcode 4.6.x?

Tags: xcode, debugging, xcode4.6

It seems reasonably widely acknowledged that [it is slow to use the `po` command in Xcode 4.6.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760206/po-command-in-xcode-4-6-is-very-slow-the-first-time).  What are the options for inspecting the values of arbitrary variables unspecified at compile time (which rules out usage of `NSLog()`) which don't take > 15s?

Comment: By marking breakpoint, and moving the mouse pointer to that variable

Comment: @AnoopVaidya no dice - see [here](http://picpaste.com/pics/Screen_Shot_2013-04-13_at_11.58.11_PM-jgwMuzoL.1365861570.png)

Comment: How that popup window came? right clicked?

Comment: no just hovering over the variable and clicking on the arrow.  Are you using 4.6?

Comment: yes...... It should work. Check with some other XCode on diffrnt systems. get conformed and then re-install XCode.

Comment: Thanks, reinstalling Xcode is a bit drastic and like I said I'd just like to be able to run the `po` command anyways.  A lot of other people are having the same problem so I'm hoping a fix is on the way.

Comment: A lot of people!!!!! Let me check again with XCode4.6.1. I have XCode4.6.0 there it is perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer is pretty simple: download Xcode 4.6.2 where LLDB debugging speed has been increased significantly.  Note some discussion over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16174609/392653)

Answer (score 4):

Just set a breakpoint where you want to learn the variables' value. Once the program is paused, a summary of all the variables' value will appear on the `Varibles view` on the left-bottom of the screen. Here is a screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried doing this with Xcode 4.6?  There is a lag of up to 30s to right click on one of the variables in that pane, not to mention objects, ivars etc.

Comment: Well I'm using 4.6.1 and I have no lag at all when I right-click. And why to right-click? You have the values without clicking.

Comment: what if it is a dictionary?  or an ivar which you want to inspect?

Comment: I have a little dictionary with 3 key/value pairs, still not any lag or delay.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lldb commands:

```
p (int) myInt
po myObject
po myObject.memberObject
p (float) myObject.floatMember
```

Just a note, you could also use p instead of po in the newest version of Xcode. If you run the `help -a` in llb, it will present you with command aliases, below is a snippet of the commands you could use.

```
> (lldb) help -a  
p         -- ('expression --')  Evaluate a C/ObjC/C++ expression in the current
         program context, using user defined variables and variables
         currently in scope.  

po        -- ('expression -o  --')  Evaluate a C/ObjC/C++ expression in the
         current program context, using user defined variables and
         variables currently in scope  

print     -- ('expression --')  Evaluate a C/ObjC/C++ expression in the current
         program context, using user defined variables and variables
         currently in scope.
```

Comment: the problem with Xcode 4.6 is that for many users the `p`/`po` commands are very slow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760206/po-command-in-xcode-4-6-is-very-slow-the-first-time